# How to move any line in a text file or any element in xml file up or down 1 line at a time using Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
line4
.....
```

and xml file

```
<names>
    <name A </name>
    <name B </name>
    <name C </name>
    <name D </name>
    <name E </name>
    ...............
</names>
```

I like to move any line 1 line up (EX: line 2 or name D up 1 line)

```
line0
line2
line1
line3
line4
.....


<names>
    <name A </name>
    <name B </name>
    <name D </name>
    <name C </name>
    <name E </name>
    ...............
</names>
```

or 1 line down (EX: line 3 or name B down 1 line)

```
line0
line1
line2
line4
line3
.....


<names>
    <name A </name>
    <name C </name>
    <name B </name>
    <name D </name>
    <name E </name>
    ...............
</names>
```

How to get it done using Python?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list:

```
def movelineup(filename, linenum):
    if linenum == 1 or linenum > len(filename):
        return None
    filelines = []
    f = open('test.txt', 'r+')
    for i in range(0, len(filename)):
        filelines.append(f.readline())
    filelines[linenum - 2], filelines[linenum - 1] =\
        filelines[linenum - 1], filelines[linenum - 2]
    f.seek(0)
    for line in filelines:
        f.write(line)



movelineup('test.txt', 3)

line0 # line 1
line2 # line 2
line1 # line 3
line3 # line 4
line4 # line 5
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great.